# Regular expression error in Flex

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I'm learning to write a lexer with Flex and I found a weird problem.
I tried to define the regular expression of keyword **class**.

For my test case:

```
class T{
}
```

Expression 1:

```
ws [\t\r\f\v ]
CLASS (^class$)|(^class{ws})|({ws}class{ws})|({ws}class$)
```

doesn't work.

Expression 2:

```
ws [\t\r\f\v ]
CLASS ^class{ws}
```

works.

Expression 3:

```
ws [\t\r\f\v ]
CLASS1 ^class{ws}
CLASS {CLASS1}
```

reports error saying ***unrecognized rule***.

I feel so confused and is there any difference between 2 and 3?
I refer to examples on [Flex github](https://github.com/westes/flex/blob/master/examples/testxxLexer.l). It just uses similar expressions to define number.

Any help will be appreciated!

**Update:**

My script:

```
%{

/* Some include headers here */

/* The compiler assumes these identifiers. */
#define yylval cool_yylval
#define yylex  cool_yylex

/* Max size of string constants */
#define MAX_STR_CONST 1025
#define YY_NO_UNPUT   /* keep g++ happy */

extern FILE *fin; /* we read from this file */

/* define YY_INPUT so we read from the FILE fin:
 * This change makes it possible to use this scanner in
 * the Cool compiler.
 */
#undef YY_INPUT
#define YY_INPUT(buf,result,max_size) \
        if ( (result = fread( (char*)buf, sizeof(char), max_size, fin)) < 0) \
                YY_FATAL_ERROR( "read() in flex scanner failed");

char string_buf[MAX_STR_CONST]; /* to assemble string constants */
char *string_buf_ptr;
extern int curr_lineno;
extern int verbose_flag;
extern YYSTYPE cool_yylval;

%}

/*
 * Define names for regular expressions here.
 */
ws              [\t\r\f\v ]
CLASS1          {ws}class$
CLASS2          ^class$
CLASS3          ^class{ws}
CLASS4          {ws}class{ws}
CLASS           {CLASS2}
DARROW          =>
STRING          \"[^\n"]+\"

%%
{CLASS} {return (CLASS);}  /*returned CLASS is defined in other header files*/
%%
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Can you post a minimal-but-complete flex file that produces the "unrecognized rule" error?

Comment: @sepp2k I update the flex file. `CLASS  {CLASS2}` causes error but `CLASS {CLASS1}` is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is unnecessary: you can just use `class` as your regex without any anchors or mentions of white space. You're probably defining it like that because you want to avoid the regex matching part of a larger identifier (e.g. you don't want `classOf99` to be interpreted as the keyword `class`, followed by the identifier `Of99`), but that's not going to happen: When there are multiple regexen that could match on the current input, Flex will always take the one that leads to the longest match (and in case of ties, it will pick the one that comes first in the flex file). This is known as the maximal munch rule and avoids exactly this issue.

So your code should just be `class { return CLASS; }` and none of the definitions are necessary.

---

That said, here's why your attempts did not work:

You can not use `^` and `$`. Some times this will lead to "unrecognized rules", other times it will just fail to match.

So that explains why your first definition does not work. But why does the second not work? If you use definitions inside of other definitions, they're implicitly wrapped in parentheses to avoid precedence issues. So you can't use definitions using `^` or `$` inside other definitions either.

So the only way to have multiple alternatives involving `^` and `$` would be to have separate rules like this:

```
^re  { return X; }
re$  { return X; }
```

But again, this really isn't necessary in your case (or ever).

Comment: I get your point. You're right. But I am wondering is there a situation requiring `^` inside parentheses and how flex deals with this kind of thing?

Comment: @lionel Some things become harder to express, but you should always be able to rewrite the rules to make it work. That is, instead of `(^foo)|(foo$) {...}`, you can just write `^foo {...}` and then `foo$ {...}` (perhaps putting the `...` code into its own function to avoid code duplication). Note that you only need `^` if you want to recognize certain keywords only at the beginning of the line, which isn't that common a use case to begin with. And when that use case does come, you usually don't need to use `|` with it. So it should rarely, if ever, be an issue in practice.

Comment: Clear! Thanks so much~